# Doucet Notation- d in expectation estimate

Tags: bayesian, particle-filter

In the book Sequential Monte Carlo Methods in Practice, the beginning of section 1.3.1. I am confused by the notation used

$$P_N(dx_{0:t}|y_{0:t})=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\delta_{x_{0:t}^{(i)}}(dx_{0:t})}$$

This is what is referred to as the empirical estimate of the posterior distribution. I would like to know what does $d$ mean inside this equation. Does it simply denote the fact that this equation is an estimate or does it mean as an "instance when the probability density is evaluated" or something else.

Comment: It could mean literally anything. It looks like "$dx$" is used as a single symbol where other authors might use "$x$" or "$X$", but it's impossible to tell from looking only at this formula. How does the book's author define his/her notation?

Comment: @whuber There is a footnote describing this. It states $p(\mathbf {dx_t})$ to represent continuous probability distributions and $p(\mathbf {x_t})$ to represent discrete probability distributions. And that occasionally $p(\mathbf {x_t})$ "shall sometimes refer to a distribution".  I assume the last sentence means that the notation is used generally for both discrete and continuous, but nothing I can be completely sure of

Comment: @whuber that being said, in this case the formula above represents the empirical estimate wrt to the distribution of the posterior with "continuous" rv's. I guess I answered my own question but perhaps someone who is used to reading this notation can let me know

Comment: I agree it looks like an empirical distribution--but it appears to have an awful lot of superfluous junk, and if it really does attempt to describe an empirical distribution (which perforce is *discrete*, not continuous) then using the "$d$" is awfully inconsistent!

Comment: Are you sure there should be a superscript inside th parentheses on the right hand side?

Comment: @Taylor youre right. Ill edit

Comment: Cool, what about the capitalization thing I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typically $\delta_x(A)$ is the Dirac measure that puts all it's mass on $x$. So it will evaluate to $1$ if $x \in A$, and $0$ otherwise. That is, it's $1$ if $A$ covers $x$, the support. The important thing is that it is a measure, so the arguments to this function are sets.
2. Sometimes in particle filtering people capitalize the subscript, too, to emphasize that the support is random (your random samples/particles). You haven't, but perhaps you meant to. In either event, the subscript will denote the support, so $\delta_{X_{0:t}^i}(dx_{0:t})$ is the measure that evaluates to $1$ if $X^i_{0:t} \in dx_{0:t}$. Or in other words, if your $i$th particle is in the set that is chosen.
3. He is writing $dx_{0:t}$ instead of $x_{0:t}$ because he wants to be general and not talk about continuous or discrete random variables specifically. Also, he wants to emphasize what is the argument to the measure, and what's the support. So the Lebesgue integral, which has the same definition for both continuous and discrete r.v.s, of any function can be taken with respect to this empirical/approximate measure:

\begin{align*}
E_{P_N(dx_{0:t}|y_{0:t})}[h(X_{0:t})] &= \int h(x_{0:t}) p_N(dx_{0:t}) \\
&= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N h(X^i_{0:t}).
\end{align*}

If you have a page number you want me to refer to, or if I was wrong about $dx_{0:t}$ not having a superscript, feel free to comment below. I have the book in my office I think.

Comment: thanks. With regards to the use of the subscript, in page 7 (of my edition) i.e. the beginning of section 1.3.1, the subscript $\mathbf{x_{0:t}^{i}}$ does not seem to be capitalised.